# Struct or union expected

Tags: c, pointers

This code results in the `struct or union expected` error:

```c
void doSomething(Animation* anim) {
    anim->quad.x = anim.x * anim.currFrame;
}
```

anim.quad is a `Rectangle` with the following declaration

```c
typedef struct Rectangle {
    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    float height;
} Rectangle;
```

Definition of `Animation`:

```c
typedef struct Animation {
    int currFrame;
    int framesCount;
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    Texture2D image;
    Rectangle quad;
    Color tint;
} Animation;
```

Exact error message:

```
animate.c:44: error: struct or union expected
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Animation`?

Comment: Please include a proper [mcve] and the exact error message

Comment: In order to answer the question, we'll need you to make a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `anim` is a pointer. You cannot use dot with pointers `anim.NONONO` (possibly `anim->OKOK` or `(*anim).OKOK`)

Comment: @pmg oh i'm sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that `anim` is a pointer to an `Animation`, not an honest-to-goodness `Animation` object. That means that if you want to select a field from the `Animation` pointed at by `anim`, you need to use the `->` operator rather than the `.` operator. To fix the error, change

```
anim->quad.x = anim.x * anim.currFrame;
```

to read

```
anim->quad.x = anim->x * anim->currFrame;
```

More generally, if you find yourself getting this error message, check to see whether you're mixing up `.` and `->`.